# How to automatically color text depending by programming language in C# richtextbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

Maybe my question already have posted previously but I didn't find.

I have WinForm (C#) and I put a richtextbox.

I want to paste a SQL code and I want that reserved keywords from pasted text to be colored in blue or other specific color for reserved keyword.

How to achieve this in C# code if is possible ?

Comment: It's possible, in fact it's been done a few times. Do you want to reinvent the wheel or just get it done? More than afew open source implementations if you want to do a bit of each.

Comment: Propose me some source code which staisfy my need.

Comment: What did your last slave die of? It's called Google.

Comment: I prefer Bing but sometimes I forget to type `bing.com` and instead type `google.com` - so funny :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for something called syntax highlighting. There are multiple libraries available to do this, but i would recommend taking a look at http://colorcode.codeplex.com/

Comment: It just add <div> tags to richtextbox...I want to appear as colored text, no html syntax.

Comment: Excuse me, I thought ColorCode also had Controls for WinForm applications. However, googling around led to a lot of other possible solutions for your problem (for example http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/161871/Fast-Colored-TextBox-for-syntax-highlighting). I'd suggest you google around for "syntax highlighting for .net applications" yourself and find what suits your needs the best.